# PHP: curl_exec() of html content is different from view page source

Tags: php, parsing, curl, web-scraping

Html output of below code gives some additional data which are not at all available                                                                                    in page. I compare this output with view page source. Extra data start from "Find a different......"

```
$url : http://www.linkedin.com/pub/senthil-selvaraj/36/90b/5b9
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           "$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,       30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,     "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,     "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01;    Windows    NT 5.0)");

 if ($proxystatus == 'on')
 {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
 }            

 $body = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably connected to cookies or headers, as cURL does not emulate real browser in all ways. Therefore, your output can differ, since cURL can even send different Accept or Location headers etc.

Have you tried different browsers? Also, is that cURL going out from the same IP you are browsing the page?

**EDIT:** What you can try to do is install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) into Firefox, then open it using F12 key, switch to Net (or Network) tab and check what headers your browser sends to the server. Then, you may be able to emulate these headers using your cURL request.

Comment: Apart from page information , curl_exec adds suggestion information also in the output. Output shows many other url which contain senthil selvaraj name.

Comment: I understand that :) but can you answer those 2 questions in my answer?

Comment: I didnt try with other browser but same ip